# Error in configure.ac file while running aclocal

Tags: autoconf, automake

I am following https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install to learn how to use `autoconf` and `automake` to create the `configure` script and `Makefile`.

Below is the content of `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_INIT ([helloworld], [0.1], [someone@nowhere.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

However, when I run `aclocal` command, I get the following error.

```
user $ aclocal
configure.ac:2: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
/usr/share/aclocal-1.14/init.m4:29: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:2: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
user $
```

I did google search to see if line `AC_INIT ([helloworld], [0.1], [someone@nowhere.com])` was incorrect. But it looks like it is correct way to use `AC_INIT`.

How do I fix this ?

Also, below is the content of `Makefile.am` file (if this is related to the error):

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = helloworld
helloworld_SOURCES = hello.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be just a matter of whitespace: according to [3.1.2 The Autoconf Language](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Autoconf-Language) from the [Autoconf Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html):

> When calling macros that take arguments, there must not be any white
>   space between the macro name and the open parenthesis.
>
> ```
>  AC_INIT ([oops], [1.0]) # incorrect
>  AC_INIT([hello], [1.0]) # good
> ```

So you need to change

```
AC_INIT ([helloworld], [0.1], [someone@nowhere.com])
```

to

```
AC_INIT([helloworld], [0.1], [someone@nowhere.com])
```